# Registering multiple Services and configure route in KONG with file

Tags: kubernetes, kong, amazon-eks, microk8s

Whenever I need to register my EKS services and required routes with kong, I have to manually execute CURL method( post/get ) commands for same, Services and routes get register successfully, but my requirement is to build or automate above multiple configurations with KONG, some way like producing a `YAML` file for all service registrations and routes for KONG and then executing at once.

I explored all the sources, even KONG official documentation, but couldn't find any way which ease my requirement

```
###################### Adding Svc ##########################################

curl -k -i -X POST \
  --url https://localhost:7001/services/ \
  --data 'name=hello-world1' \
  --data 'host=service-helloworld' \
  --data 'port=80'  


###################### Adding Route ##########################################

curl -k -i -X POST --url https://localhost:7001/services/hello-world/routes --data 'paths=/hello-world' --data 'methods[]=GET'
```

Some way to automate above `CURL` commands

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly those are some of the ways you are looking for:

#### [Container Lifecycle Hooks](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/containers/container-lifecycle-hooks/)

In your case you would want to use `PostStart`

> This hook executes immediately after a container is created. However, there is no guarantee that the hook will execute before the container ENTRYPOINT. No parameters are passed to the handler.
>
> #### Hook handler implementations
>
> Containers can access a hook by implementing and registering a handler for that hook. There are two types of hook handlers that can be implemented for Containers:
>
> - Exec - Executes a specific command, such as  `pre-stop.sh`, inside the cgroups and namespaces of the Container. Resources consumed by the command are counted against the Container.
> - HTTP - Executes an HTTP request against a specific endpoint on the Container.

Your `pod` might look like the following example:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: lifecycle-demo
spec:
  containers:
  - name: lifecycle-demo-container
    image: nginx
    lifecycle:
      postStart:
        exec:
          command: 
           - "sh"
           - "-c"
           - >
             curl -k -i -X POST --url https://localhost:7001/services/ --data 'name=hello-world1' --data 'host=service-helloworld' --data 'port=80';
             curl -k -i -X POST --url https://localhost:7001/services/hello-world/routes --data 'paths=/hello-world' --data 'methods[]=GET'
```

#### [Init Containers](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/init-containers/)

> A  [Pod](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod-overview/)  can have multiple containers running apps within it, but it can also have one or more init containers, which are run before the app containers are started.
>
> Init containers are exactly like regular containers, except:
>
> - Init containers always run to completion.
> - Each init container must complete successfully before the next one starts.

And here is an example from [docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/init-containers/#init-containers-in-use):

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: myapp-pod
  labels:
    app: myapp
spec:
  containers:
  - name: myapp-container
    image: busybox:1.28
    command: ['sh', '-c', 'echo The app is running! && sleep 3600']
  initContainers:
  - name: init-myservice
    image: busybox:1.28
    command: ['sh', '-c', 'until nslookup myservice; do echo waiting for myservice; sleep 2; done;']
  - name: init-mydb
    image: busybox:1.28
    command: ['sh', '-c', 'until nslookup mydb; do echo waiting for mydb; sleep 2; done;']
```